# Python - SelectFromModel with Naive-Bayes

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I am using [SelectFromModel](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html) in combination with [MultinomialNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html) for feature selection in a text classification task.

```
SelectFromModel(estimator=MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0))
```

SelectFromModel determines the importance from features by computing:

```
importances = np.linalg.norm(estimator.coef_, axis=0,ord=norm_order)
```

But isn't this exactly the opposite of what I want, because features with a high frequency will result in low absolute values?

There are already multiple well answered questions for determining the importance of features given a specific class, but not for feature importance in general.

Is there a way to determine the feature importance with SelectFromModel in combination with NB or are other approaches better suited for this task?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more. What do you mean by "eatures with a high frequency" ? Also, this is a classification task, so obviously feature importance will be according to the classes. Can you explain in detail what you want?

Comment: I mean features with high term frequency (in a document), for example using a CountVectorizer. SelectFromModel basically determines the importance for each feature in a classification task, and selects the "most important features" which should work fine classifiers like SVC, but as I tried to explain, it doesn't seem to work for NB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function known as Recursive Feature Elimination with Cross Validation, also known as [RFECV in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV). It tries to rank the features according to their importance recursively and performs cross-validation to get the best number of features with the estimator specified. You can look at the [example here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py) for more information.

I am not sure why selectFromModel is not working with NaiveBayes. I will update this answer if I find anything related to it. In the mean time, you can check RFECV suits your needs.